# Log out current user programmatically or restart X server (work around xlock race condition)

Tags: x11, logout

We currently use xlock to provide a logout button for people who want to start using a computer locked by someone else. Unfortunately,this logout process is prone to a race condition, where the xlock process dies before the rest of the session, which could lead to overtaking the session that is being logged out.

We have an inhomogeneous environment where users run a variety of window managers. What I'm looking for is a way to either log out the current user in a window-manager agnostic fashion (meaning, no potential at all for a race condition where the screen locker dies before rest of the session) or emulate ctrl + alt + backspace programmatically, to force X to restart (without using root, as the screenlocker shouldn't be setuid root).

Comment: You didn't say what you are currently doing to log out the user, but killing the window manager is in most setups what forces the display manager to start a new session. This is independent of the type of window manager, and also shouldn't lead to a race condition (xlock sends kill signal, window managers kills children including xlock). So that's what I'd try to implement.

Comment: xlock has that functionality built-in, and the source is a bit hard to follow. My question is, how do I reliably identify which process to kill? How will I know what the window manager is when I don't know which one it is?

Comment: Your display manager (gdm/kdm/xdm, whatever you use) stays the same, so look for children of it (using `ps --ppid` or `pstree`, and excluding the X server, of course). If you can launch a shell script from xlock (or modify the source to do it), it shouldn't be too difficult to do.